# Angular 2 routing in production dist

Tags: routes, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, router

My angular 2 app works fine with routes, I have two routes setup for 2 different components (/integrations and /steps). On ng server works fine. Now we need to move to apache, in order to use pure html/js/css. However when I move the dist folder to htdocs and try to access localhost/dist/integrations, I get error 500 internal server error. I looked into apache log and saw that apache is doing more then 10 redirections inside, which causes the error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

just add .htaccess file, 
more info you can find here https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: Answers that are basically just links will age poorly. Can you expand on the relevant details here?